# NSTimer crashing and causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer, appdelegate, nstimeinterval

I have to check whether user touching a screen or not. If user touch the screen i'm not doing any event. If user doesn't touch the screen and release the finger from any touch i'm couting the second, if it reach 15 or so on i'm doing some other event. Here i'm displaying NSLog time exceeded value. Whhen user release the finger after 15secs the time exceeded log is showing. But after i do any button click action my app crashing.

TIMERUIApplication.h

```
 #define kApplicationTimeoutInMinutes 0.2

 //the notification your AppDelegate needs to watch for in order to know that it has indeed "timed out"
 #define kApplicationDidTimeoutNotification @"AppTimeOut"

 @interface TIMERUIApplication : UIApplication
 {
 NSTimer     *myidleTimer;
 }

 -(void)resetIdleTimer;

 @end
```

TIMERUIApplication.m:

```
#import "TIMERUIApplication.h"

 @implementation TIMERUIApplication

 //here we are listening for any touch. If the screen receives touch, the timer is reset
 -(void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
 [super sendEvent:event];

 if (!myidleTimer)
 {
 [self resetIdleTimer];
 }

 NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
 if ([allTouches count] > 0)
 {
 UITouchPhase phase = ((UITouch *)[allTouches anyObject]).phase;
 if (phase == UITouchPhaseBegan)
 {
 [self resetIdleTimer];
 }

 }
 }
 //as labeled...reset the timer
 -(void)resetIdleTimer
 {
 if (myidleTimer)
 {
 [myidleTimer invalidate];
 myidleTimer=nil;
 }
 //convert the wait period into minutes rather than seconds
 int timeout = kApplicationTimeoutInMinutes * 60;
 myidleTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeout target:self selector:@selector(idleTimerExceeded) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

 }
 //if the timer reaches the limit as defined in kApplicationTimeoutInMinutes, post this notification
 -(void)idleTimerExceeded
 {
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kApplicationDidTimeoutNotification object:nil];
 }


 @end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
 self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

 self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];

 UINavigationController *nav1=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

 self.window.rootViewController = nav1;

 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidTimeout:) name:kApplicationDidTimeoutNotification object:nil];

 return YES;
 }

 -(void)applicationDidTimeout:(NSNotification *) notif
 {
 NSLog (@"time exceeded!!");


}
```

Comment: Turn on breakpoint all exception and see what line causing it.

Comment: post your error Logs/error

Comment: I got working. I have to remove if (!myidleTimer)
 {
 [self resetIdleTimer];
 } and need to change here also: if (phase == UITouchPhaseBegan || phase == UITouchPhaseEnded)